# Two-sum solution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, interview-questions, ecmascript-6, k-sum

I was given this question during an interview. It is similar to two sum problems and I would like to ask for feedback for my solution.

> Merging 2 Packages
>
> Given a package with a weight limit limit and an array arr of item
>   weights, implement a function getIndicesOfItemWeights that finds two
>   items whose sum of weights equals the weight limit limit. Your
>   function should return a pair [i, j] of the indices of the item
>   weights, ordered such that i > j. If such a pair doesn’t exist, return
>   an empty array.
>
> Example:
>
> input:  arr = [4, 6, 10, 15, 16],  lim = 21
>
> output: [3, 1] # since these are the indices of the
>                  # weights 6 and 15 whose sum equals to 21 Constraints:
>
> [time limit] 5000ms
>
> [input] array.integer arr
>
> 0 ≤ arr.length ≤ 100 [input] integer limit
>
> [output] array.integer

```js
function getIndicesOfItemWeights(arr, limit) {  
  let weights = {};
  let result = []
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let compliment = limit - arr[i];
    if (typeof weights[compliment]!= "undefinded"){
      if (i > (weights[compliment])){
        result.push(weights[compliment], i);
        //return [i, weights[compliment]];
      } else {
        return [weights[compliment] , i];
      }
    } else {
      weights[arr[i]] = i; // put new weight into weight obj
     
    }
  }
  return [];

}

let arr = [4, 6, 10, 15, 16];
let limit = 21;
console.log(getIndicesOfItemWeights(arr, limit))


// output: [3, 1] # since these are the indices of the
// weights 6 and 15 whose sum equals to 21
```

Comment: Your code logs `[undefined, 0]` - should it actually log  `[3, 1]`?

Comment: Is the array of weights sorted?

Comment: As Sam Onela pointed out, the code doesn't work as intended, returning `[undefined, 0]` instead of `[3, 1]`. The commented out `return` statement looks suspicious, so is the typo "undefinded" (instead of `undefined`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my updated solution after the code review:

```
let getIndicesOfItemWeights = function(arr, limit) {
  let map = new Map()
  let indices = []
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let difference = limit-arr[i]
    if(map.has(difference)){
      indices.push(i, map.get(difference))
      return indices
    } else {
      map.set(arr[i], i)
    }
  }
  return indices
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to aproach this, somehow i find your solution alittle bit difficult to read but i like the idea of using `compliment = limit - arr[i];`

a simpler way would be either using nested `for` loops :

```js
const getIndicesOfItemWeights = (arr, limit) => {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (result[0] && result[1]) break; // break out of the loop if the result is full.

    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] === limit) { // if the sum of two elements is eqaul to the limit.
        result.push(i, j); // push the indices to the result array.        
        break; // break out of the second loop
      }
    }
  }

  return result.sort((a, b) => b - a);
}

const arr = [4, 6, 10, 15, 16];
const limit = 21;

const x = getIndicesOfItemWeights(arr, limit);
console.log(x)
```

or take the shortcut of using the `compliment = limit - arr[i];`

```js
const arr = [4, 6, 10, 15, 16];
const limit = 21;

const getIndicesOfItemWeights = (arr, limit) => {
  let result = [];

  arr.forEach(e => {
    const a = arr.find(x => x === limit - e);
    if (a && result.length === 0) { // if the element is found and the array is empty, push the indices to the result array
      result.push(arr.indexOf(e), arr.indexOf(a));
      return;
    }
  })

  return result.sort((a, b) => b - a);
}

const x = getIndicesOfItemWeights(arr, limit);
console.log(x)
```